# Reason for "Neural networks are exceptionally good at coming up with good features for highly structured data"

Tags: deep-learning, q-learning

I was reading about deep Q-learning and came across this statement

> Neural networks are exceptionally good at coming up with good features
>   for highly structured data

from [this](https://www.intelnervana.com/demystifying-deep-reinforcement-learning/) blog.

I want to why that happens and proof for that ?

Comment: It's from empirical observation from what I've seen, so you're not going to get a proof for this, at most some hypothesis. We have the universal approximation theorem, and not much besides that.

Answer (score 1):

That quote is basically a tautological statement if you assume that the network converges to its true parameter values.

A neural network is defined as 
$$
y = a(a(a(...a(a(X\Gamma_L)\Gamma_{L-1}...)\Gamma_3)\Gamma_2)\Gamma_1 + \epsilon
$$
Define 
$$
V \equiv a(f(\Gamma_{2:L}, X))
$$
and
$$
\hat{y} = V\Gamma_1
$$

Those $V$ are derived features, related linearly to the outcome by weights $\Gamma$.  They are "good" features if $E[(y-\hat{y})^2]$ is small.  And this tends to be the case, because neural nets typically perform quite well once tuned adequately.

The statement is tautological because deriving features is precisely what a neural network does.  A neural net is basically a regressor-picker for OLS (or for penalized regression, or a penalized GLM).

(Obviously this is for the squared error loss, but the generalization to classification is simple).